# Retrieve sapui5 BSP from NW ABAP system

Tags: visual-studio-code, gruntjs, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I know the grunt plugin 'grunt-nwabap-ui5uploader', to deploy an UI5 webapp to the netweaver ABAP system. 
Therefor I can use any IDE to develop and push my apps to the system. In my case I would love to use Visual Studio Code.

Is there any plugin to do the similar but retrieve the existing bsp application, similar as ithe eclipse plugin for UI5 development.

Or is it even possible to develop?

Comment: I suppose it is impossible to retrieve BSP-app to VS, as it has totally different nature from UI5. Maybe only the simplest apps

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to import the application from the SAP Netwaever systems BSP repository into the SAP WebIDE which serves for SAPUI5 and Fiori development.

Import UI5 App:

[image: Screenshot Import UI5 App]

Then you export to your computer as a zip:

[image: Screenshot Export to local files as zip]

Prerequisites: if you work with UI5 apps, you should have access to SAP WebIDE by your company already, which is the standard tool to manage UI5 and Fiori applications. SAP WebIDE is connected via Cloud Connector to your Netweaver ABAP system.

There is however a manual way to do this for individual file access:
You log on to SAP via SAP GUI and start transaction SE80, where you have access to the BSP repository, which serves as a storage for UI5 applications:

[image: Screenshot SE80 BSP Repo]

You can also dump the app to text files executing report BSP_EXPORT_CLASSES in transaction SE38. Here enter the name of the BSP application found in SE80.
Good luck!

Comment: Interesting ideas.  The BSP_EXPORT_CLASSES does a good job at Export. I just checked. Hadnt seen that before thanks.   I couldnt find the import version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the check in check out process without the eclipse plug-in is tricky to deal with.
You could "try" to checkout `Team->share`  the UI5 app in eclipse.   Then `export` the project using `file` level export tool.

From there edit with VS code.

Import back in or manually include changes back into Eclipse.

Then using eclipse to check into SAP Backend.

Unfortunately accessing directly from Se80 in backend there is no export / import tool for files except for mimes. So unless you know how to call the plug-in interfaces, you would be creating or changing files and pasting code manually.

Writing the VS code plugin to do the check in and check out isnt impossible,
but the eclipse plugin uses rest and SAP proprietary RFC calls.  Ive not seen docu on the interfaces. They may be internal only.

Its not easy to recommend what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the report `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD` in the transaction `SE38`.

Just provide the name of the BSP application, an encoding (`UTF-8`) and a directory where to put the source code.

It is recommended to create a new directory somewhere, you don't want 30 new files and folders directly on your desktop.